# Showing that the radius of convergence of $\sum_{\nu = 0}^\infty \frac{B_{\nu}}{\nu !}z^\nu$ is at most $2\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function $f: B_{2\pi}(0) \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$\begin{align}f(z) := \begin{cases} z/(e^z - 1) & z \neq 0\\
1 & z = 0
\end{cases}\end{align}$$
It is well known, that the Taylor expansion of $f$ around $0$ is given by $$\sum_{\nu = 0}^\infty \frac{B_{\nu}}{\nu !}z^\nu$$ where $B_\nu$ are the Bernoulli numbers of the first kind. I know that the radius of convergence of the Taylor expansion is $2\pi$. First, from the expansion lemma we get that the radius of convergence is at least $2\pi$ since $f$ is a holomorphic function in $B_{2\pi}(0)$ and has therefore a Taylor expansion there which converges there. And here is my question: **Why is the radius of convergence at most $2\pi$?** I mean , I know that $$\lim_{z \to 2\pi i} f(z) = \infty$$ and so also $$\lim_{z \to 2\pi i}\sum_{\nu = 0}^\infty \frac{B_{\nu}}{\nu !}z^\nu = \infty$$ So $\sum_{\nu = 0}^\infty \frac{B_{\nu}}{\nu !}z^\nu$ simply does not converge outside of the disc. Can someone help me formalize my thoughts?

Comment: By definition, if a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$ converges on $|z| < r$ then it is analytic on $|z| < r$. The converse is harder : if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$ diverges for $|z| > r$ then it is not analytic on $|z| < R$ for any $R > r$

Comment: So it is easy to show the radius of convergence is at most $2\pi$ since $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ has a singularity (a pole) at $z = 2i\pi$, and it is much harder to show the radius of convergence is $2\pi$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the radius of convergence cannot exceed $2\pi$ is that there are poles at $z=\pm2\pi i.$ At those points, the denominator, $e^z-1,$ is $0$, but the numerator is a non-zero number.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate a bit more one this? I do not fully understand it yet. I know there is a singularity at $2\pi i$, but why does this mean, that also the Taylor series cannot have a larger radius of convergence?

Comment: The series $\displaystyle \sum_{\nu = 0}^\infty \frac{B_\nu}{\nu !}z^\nu$ is $\displaystyle \sum_{\nu = 0}^\infty \frac{B_\nu}{\nu !}(z-0)^\nu,$ i.e. the center of the region of convergence is $0.$ The series converges if the distance from the center to $z$ is less than the radius of convergence, and diverges if it is more. A theorem, not explicitly mentioned in my answer above, is that convergent power series are differentiable everywhere in the interior of their disk of convergence (not necessarily on the boundary, even at points on the boundary at which the series$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$converges. A function does not have a pole at a point at which it is differentable. $\qquad$